# Keep throwing exception until correct value is found

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
//Querying for move
        int playerMove = currentPlayer.PlayCard(myBoard);

        //Making move
        try {
            playMove(playerMove, currentPlayer);
        } 
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

            System.out.println("Sorry, I don't think you can do that...");

        }
```

The move the player makes needs to be associated to an index in an ArrayList. Right now, my code cathces the exception of a player making an invalid move correctly, but I would like to know how I can modify it so the player keeps being asked to make a move until they make a valid one.

Thank you! :)

Comment: You shouldn't be handling invalid moves with exceptions at all - you should be preventing them with conditionals. Exceptions are for *exceptional* behaviour - players trying to perform invalid moves are not exceptional.

Comment: In order to run a code multiple times, you can use for/while loop

Comment: @AntP it's console based. I output a list of available moves (ie: input integer 1-5), but if the user inputs 6 what should I do other than throwing an exceptions? :\

Comment: @DarioPanada You should have a conditional statement that checks that the input integer is within the acceptable range. Catching exceptions for this sort of thing is sloppy and inefficient.

Comment: @AntP so something like generating an arrayList of possible moves and prompting user until what they enter matches one of them? Then use exception to catch for example if use enters a String instead of an int (since the method I use to read values only accepts ints)?

Comment: @Dario Panada, indeed. That's way better.

Comment: You probably don't need to create an array of possible moves, you just need to check that, for example, `currentPosition + changeInPosition >= 0` and `currentPosition + changeInPosition < numberOfSpacesOnBoard`. You can also do a similar check that they've entered a numeric value. Then you can provide proper feedback.

Comment: @AntP well it's a card game, so possible moves correspond to card in hand plus eventual "draw card" or "pass move"

Comment: The same concept applies - if you can build an array of valid moves, surely you can just check the *actual* move against the same logic (since you obviously have a way of checking the validity of moves in order to do this)? Rather than spend time and memory on building up and checking against an array? However, if not; yes, the array is still preferable to just catching exceptions here.

Comment: @AntP yes, I do have a logic to check valid moves, and that is used to print to screen the list of available moves. As I print them to screen, each index is added to the array. I thought it was better than applying the logic twice, what do you suggest?

Comment: @DarioPanada If you already have that list of valid moves then, yes, it probably makes sense just to check against that list.

Answer (score 5):

Use a while loop

```
while(!IsMoveValid)
{
    int playerMove = currentPlayer.PlayCard(myboard);
    IsMoveValid = CheckMoveValidity(playerMove, myBoard);
}
playMove(playerMove, currentPlayer);
```

and

```
public bool CheckMoveValidity(int move, Board board)
{
    if (move > 0) && (move < board.Length)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    // you could make this helper method shorter by doing
    // return (move > 0) && (move < board.Length);
}
```

Note this doesn't use exceptions in the logic :)

Answer (score 1):

As easy as a cake

```
while(true){
    //Querying for move
    int playerMove = currentPlayer.PlayCard(myBoard);

    //Making move
    try {
        playMove(playerMove, currentPlayer);
        break; // break the while loop
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
         System.out.println("Sorry, I don't think you can do that...");
    }
}
```